# Typescript doesn't compiles paths in tsconfig

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

This is an old question, but I haven't found the exact answer.

I want to reference my modules in my TS project without using '../../../etc' import syntax.
I made the following changes:

```
...
baseUrl: ".",
paths: {
  "@orm/*": ["./src/orm/*"]
}
...
```

the IDE is happy (VSCode) and intellisense respect when I reference

```
import {} from '@orm/something'
```

but when I compile it, I get require('@orm/something') in my compiled js file and of course this path doesn't exists.

Example of compiled folder:

```
dst\
--orm\
----something.js
--another_folder\
----myfile.js (here is import {} from '@orm/something')
```

And here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dst",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@orm/*": ["./src/orm/*"]
    }
  },
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong, I don't want to use somethin like webpack to workaround, I want to keep my folder structure for the development.

Please help)

Comment: As long as you stay in development may be it is an option to remove "outDir": "dst" in your compiler options. With the compilation  to dst you move your files and the reference is broken.

Comment: Even if I would do so there is no folder @orm. Anyhow this is not the right way, it should be an alias and it should be transpiled to existing address.